# Using din rail terminal to UART communication

Tags: uart, serial, din

Can I use din rail terminal to do the communication between arduino and sensor using uart protocol? Using din terminal can I have problems? Or is better to use DB9 connector? The distance is 4m and the baud rate is 9600.

Comment: You may use whatever connection scheme is convenient for your application.  Personally, I'd probably wire directly from the sensor to the arduino, with no intervening connectors - but I don't know your situation...

Comment: with 4m x 9600 bps, shouldn't make any difference

Comment: The connector does not matter. 4m is very long for TTL level wiring without tranceivers though. Is the communication done at TTL/CMOS levels or are tranceivers such as RS-232 used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good if you used some kind of serial transceiver, like a MAX232 or whatever is trendy these days. The raw serial port from the MCU is:

- Weak: 0 to 5V with some milliamp available;
- Susceptible to noise: the input of a GPIO pin is very high impedance so it's very sensible to whatever passes by;
- Quite frail: you are pulling out in a wiring cabinet an MCU pin, without protection from all surges and bad things that are out there.

If you use some serial transceiver shield, otherwise, you'll have no issues. Terminal block or DE9 (that would be the correct designation of the d-sub) are similar *except* for electrostatic shielding, if you are using a shielded cable.